# Not getting the Template Repository Layout after deploying Python 2.7 on openshift

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, openshift

I am trying to to deploy django-cms on openshift. However, after creating a Python 2.7 application (with `rhc app create django-cms python-2.7`), I don't get the default template layout [described in the doc](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_guide.html#template-repository-layout-9). Instead I get only 3 files: requirements.txt, setup.py and wsgi.py; and the openshift folder.

Is this normal? Should I rebuild the layout from there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal.  There are lots of examples on python / openshift on github.

I wrote one for django, https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django16