# Static files (images, css) are not being served Openshift 2014, Django 1.4 and Python 2.7

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, openshift

I am having a trouble hosting static images in Openshift 2014. I have tried quite a bit with htaccess setting files etc after going through internet. The problem seems to be Openshift's change in directory patterns. It has removed folders such as wsgi https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog.

Can anyone kindly help me in figuring out this problem?

Observations

1. The website, images css files all seem to work in `debug=true` mode.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem: [Not getting the Template Repository Layout after deploying Python 2.7 on openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421741/not-getting-the-template-repository-layout-after-deploying-python-2-7-on-openshi)

After inspecting the Apache configuration on the server, I found that `wsgi/static` is still served statically by Apache. So I simply did this in my repo:

```
mkdir wsgi
cd wsgi
ln -s ../mypackage/static
```

In addition you can add the following line your build hook to serve the media files

```
if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media ]; then
    mkdir $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media
fi
ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static/media
```